# How to properly configure pgBouncer transaction level pooling?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, max-connections

What is a good way to determine the number of available transaction connections when using `pgBouncer` to pool database connections?  Also, how should I determine the number of `max_connections` and `max_transaction_locks` on `postgresql.conf`?

Our application has over 200 concurrent processes, each of which regularly reads and writes to the database.  Using session-level, I would expect the number of pooled connections to be around the number of concurrent processes working on the DB at a given time, but I don't really know how to translate that to transaction-level pooling.

Thanks very much!  Let me know if more information is necessary and I will gladly oblige.

Comment: What kind of application?  Is this a web app?  A thick client?  If it is a thick client, how many queries are active, usually, at any given point, and how many connections are idle?

Comment: @Chris.  How can I check for this information?  Is there a command or SQL statement that I can run to know this?  Thanks :)

Comment: @ChrisTravers Oh, and this is a distributed application.  We have both a Web (WSGI) front end, and the concurrent processes are back-ends using SQLAlchemy and running asynchronously.

Comment: look at pg_stat_activity and compare those which are idle to those not.  The following query will do:  `select SUM(case when current_query like '%IDLE%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as idle, count(*) as total from pg_stat_activity;`